# What is wrong with this Perl code?

Tags: perl

```
$value = $list[1] ~ s/\D//g;
```

> syntax error at try1.pl line 53, near "] ~"
>
> Execution of try1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

I am trying to extract the digits from the second element of `@list`, and store it into `$value`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean =~, not ~.  ~ is a unary bitwise negation operator.

A couple of ways to do this:

```
($value) = $list[1] =~ /(\d+)/;
```

Both sets of parens are important; only if there are capturing parentheses does the match operation return actual content instead of just an indication of success, and then only in list context (provided by the list-assign operator `()=`).

Or the common idiom of copy and then modify:

```
($value = $list[1]) =~ s/\D//;
```

Comment: Actually, it's a lot like C. The operator you were using doesn't do in C what you were trying to do either. :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you wanted the `=~` operator?

P.S. note that `$value` will not get assigned the resulting string (the string itself is changed in place). `$value` will get assigned the number of substitutions that were made

Comment: Then how come it gets assigned in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577087/how-to-read-from-a-file-and-do-a-grep-in-perl/3577114#3577114)?

Comment: @values = ($list[1] =~ /\d/g);

Answer (score 1):

You said in a comment that are trying to get rid of non-digits. It looks like you are trying to preserve the old value and get the modified value in a new variable. The Perl idiom for that is:

```
 ( my $new = $old ) =~ s/\D//g;
```

Answer (score 0):

And wanted `\d`igits not non-`\D`igits. And have a superfluous `s/`ubstitute operator where a match makes more sense.

```
if ($list[1] =~ /(\d+)/) {
    $value = $1;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to remove all non digits.

Comment: TIMTOWTDI. The Perl philosohpy.

Comment: your match only works if the digits are contiguous. the search-and-replace will work on something like `$100,000` for example